# É possível compilar C/C++ de Windows/Linux para MacOs?

Tags: c++, compilação, compiladores

Em um ambiente hipotético onde eu não tenha o sistema nem como emular, seria possível compilar um aplicativo em c++? (devidamente compatível)

Eu já encontrei alguns `cross-compilers` interessantes, mas eles apenas conseguem gerar aplicativos entre as várias distribuições de linux, android e para windows.

Comment: Possível é, mas não sei se vale o trabalho.

Comment: Primeiramente, seria necessário construir um compilador capaz de gerar o código de máquina (a partir do código fonte C++) compatível com a arquitetura desse "ambiente hipotético" que vc mencionou.

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco sobre o assunto encontrei algumas ferramentas que aparentemente demandam um bom trabalho para serem preparadas mas ao final o objetivo esperado é alcançado. Seguem os links:

http://www.sandroid.org/imcross/
http://devs.openttd.org/~truebrain/compile-farm/apple-darwin9.txt
https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, é possível. Na verdade, os compiladores de C++ por si só sempre geram código multiplataforma. O que torna o código incompatível é quando o programador usa alguma biblioteca ou comando que não está disponível em outra plataforma.

Por exemplo, se o seu código usa a [WinAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2017) ele obviamente não vai rodar fora do Windows, isso não é culpa do compilador, é porque a WinAPI só existe no Windows.

Outra coisa, se você escreve um `system("cls");` o seu código não vai rodar fora do Windows, porque `cls` é um comando batch pra limpar a janela do cmd.exe, e isso obviamente só existe no Windows. (O equivalente no Linux seria `clear`)

Resumindo: Quem faz o código C++ ser dependende de plataforma não é o compilador, mas sim o programador.

Comment: Negativo, os os compiladores de C/C++ não geram código multiplataforma. Por mais simples que seja o programa se compilar em Linux gera um [ELF](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), compilar em Windows gera um [PE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) e se compilar em MacOS gera uma [Mach-O](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/mach-o/loader.h.auto.html)